# Using orWhere in bookshelf js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have build a query using bookshelf js.  When I use `orWhere` in the query it gives an error

> Object has no method 'orWhere'.

Given below is my code

```
var filters = {};

// Restaurnat id is must
if (restaurant_id != undefined) {
    filters.restaurant_id = restaurant_id
} else {
    res.json({
        status: 422,
        message: "No restaurant id provided",
        data: ""
    });
}

var query = dp.CusOrder.query('where', filters);

if (customer_name != undefined) {
    var first_name = '%' + customer_name + '%';

    query.where('first_name', 'LIKE', first_name)
        .orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', first_name);
}

query.fetchAll()
    .then(function(result) {
        res.json({
            data: result
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are using it incorrectly. Or where should be called using the query back . Like model.query(function(qb) { qb.where(...).orWhere(...);}).then(...);

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the knex query builder included with bookshelf to do this because orWhere is a knex function (bookshelf uses knex for database access).

a simple example would be the following assuming dp.CusOrder is a forged model

```
dp.CusOrder.query(function(qb) {

    qb.where(filters);

    if (customer_name != undefined) {
        var first_name = '%' + customer_name + '%';
        qb.where('first_name', 'LIKE', first_name)
        .orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', first_name);
    }
})
.then(function(result) {
    res.json({data: result})
});
```

you may need to fiddle with the andWhere and orWhere to get the correct query or you can just use whereRaw since your query is relatively small

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give a function to your query to execute

like : `...).query(qb => qb.where(first condition).orWhere(second condition)).fetch(...`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [bookshelf-eloquent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-eloquent) extension which exposes many of the Knex.js functions directly on the bookshelf model. It also adds whereLike() and orWhereLike(). Your code would then look something like this:

```
...

let query = dp.CusOrder.where(filters);

if (customer_name != undefined) {
    let first_name = '%' + customer_name + '%';

    query.whereLike('first_name', first_name)
        .orWhereLike('last_name', first_name);
}

let result = await query.fetchAll();
```